# Position sticky on table with two levels of rowspan

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position, sticky

I have this table:

```css
.level-2 [rowspan] {
    position: sticky;
    vertical-align: top;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
}
.collapsible {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(37px * 6);
}
.collapsible table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="level-2 agragated-2-row">
        <th rowspan="9">DEV</th>
        <td rowspan="3">Cancer Immunolofy</td>
        <td>2020</td>
        <td>4%</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2019</td>
        <td>1%</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2018</td>
        <td>2%</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
        <td rowspan="3">Immunology</td>
        <td>2020</td>
        <td>4%</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2019</td>
        <td>1%</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2018</td>
        <td>2%</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
        <td rowspan="3">Infectious Diseases</td>
        <td>2020</td>
        <td>4%</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2019</td>
        <td>1%</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2018</td>
        <td>2%</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2 agragated-2-row">
        <th rowspan="6">ED</th>
        <td rowspan="3">Cancer Immunology</td>
        <td>2020</td>
        <td>4%</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2019</td>
        <td>1%</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2018</td>
        <td>2%</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2 agragated-1-row">
        <td rowspan="3">Immunology</td>
        <td>2020</td>
        <td>4%</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2019</td>
        <td>1%</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level-2">
        <td>2018</td>
        <td>2%</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`td` with `rowspan` works correctly it's hidden when the next row appears in the table. But the first `th` element (DEV) doesn't work, it's hidden before the second `th` (ED) is showing up and also the second one is not sticky.

Here is a demo https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/NWbXoVB in the last table, `position: sticky` doesn't work correctly. How can I fix this table? I've tried to change `th` to `td` and set `strong` to make text bold but it doesn't work. The same behavior is in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by wrapping DEV and ED into div and making the div sticky:

```css
.level-2 [rowspan] {
    background: white;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.level-2 [rowspan]:not(.level-0),
.level-2 .level-0 div {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="level-2 agragated-2-row">
        <th rowspan="9" class="level-0"><div>DEV</div></th>
        <td rowspan="3">Cancer Immunolofy</td>
        <td>2020</td>
        <td>4%</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
   ...
</table>
```